# R: calculate matrix determinant for each data frame row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple data frame `dxr`:

```
       x         y 
   <dbl>     <dbl> 
 1   696 1.8095105 
 2  1916 1.3033796 
 3  2244 1.4650009 
 4  2652 1.1438132
```

I want to calculate the area of the triangle formed by every three adjacent points.

What I try is:

```
dxr <- mutate(dxr, xlag=lag(x), ylag=lag(y), xlead=lead(x), ylead=lead(y) )
dxr$area <- with(dxr, abs(det(matrix(c( xlag-xlead, x-xlead, ylag-ylead, y-ylead ), nrow=2, ncol=2)))/2)
```

I get all NAs in the `area` column even though the formula

```
abs(det(matrix(c( xlag-xlead, x-xlead, ylag-ylead, y-ylead ), nrow=2, ncol=2)))/2
```

works very well on the row values if enter them explicitly:

```
abs(det(matrix(c(696-2244, 1916-2244, 1.8095105-1.4650009, 1.3033796-1.4650009),nrow=2,ncol=2)))/2
[1] 181.5945
```

What am I missing to get the `area` column populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but there seems to also be a concise solution with determinant being calculated during the first mutate step explicitly:

```
dxr <- mutate(dxr, area=abs((lag(x)-lead(x))*(y-lead(y)) - (x-lead(x))*(lag(y)-lead(y)))/2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first remove the NAs from your data, and then to apply your function to every row. Your `with` function is taking all the rows of the dataframe in your calculus, so the Nas and all lines, making your determinant wrong even if you remove the NAs.

Here is a working dplyr solution

```
dx %>%
  mutate( xlag=lag(x), ylag=lag(y), xlead=lead(x), ylead=lead(y) ) %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(area = abs(det(matrix(c( xlag-xlead, x-xlead, ylag-ylead, y-ylead ), nrow=2, ncol=2)))/2)

 A tibble: 2 x 1
       area
      <dbl>
1 181.59446
2  85.64553
```